# Unsorted icon not appearing on sort reset on Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, reset

Im trying to follow

```js
$(function() {
    var $table = $('#mytable');
    $('#reset-link').click(function() {
      $table.trigger('filterReset').trigger('sortReset');
      return false;
    });

    $table.tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',
      sortList: [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]],
      widgets: ['filter', 'zebra']
    });
});
```

with a view to removing sorts on my jQuery UITheme Widget (Bootstrap v3.x)

The reset is working but the column that is being sorted icon does not go back to the unsorted icon.

Here is my attempt

```js
$(function() {

    // NOTE: $.tablesorter.theme.bootstrap is ALREADY INCLUDED in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js
    // file; it is included here to show how you can modify the default classes
    $.tablesorter.themes.bootstrap = {
    // these classes are added to the table. To see other table classes available,
    // look here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables
    table        : 'table table-bordered table-striped',
    caption      : 'caption',
    // header class names
    header       : 'bootstrap-header', // give the header a gradient background (theme.bootstrap_2.css)
    sortNone     : '',
    sortAsc      : '',
    sortDesc     : '',
    active       : '', // applied when column is sorted
    hover        : '', // custom css required - a defined bootstrap style may not override other classes
    // icon class names
    icons        : '', // add "icon-white" to make them white; this icon class is added to the <i> in the header
    iconSortNone : 'bootstrap-icon-unsorted', // class name added to icon when column is not sorted
    iconSortAsc  : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', // class name added to icon when column has ascending sort
    iconSortDesc : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', // class name added to icon when column has descending sort
    filterRow    : '', // filter row class; use widgetOptions.filter_cssFilter for the input/select element
    footerRow    : '',
    footerCells  : '',
    even         : '', // even row zebra striping
    odd          : '' // odd row zebra striping
    
    };
    
    $('#reset-link').click(function(e) {
    $("#receipts").trigger('sortReset');
    return false;
    });

    // call the tablesorter plugin and apply the uitheme widget
    $("#receipts").tablesorter({
    // this will apply the bootstrap theme if "uitheme" widget is included
    // the widgetOptions.uitheme is no longer required to be set
    theme : "bootstrap",

    widthFixed: true,
   

     headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // new in v2.7. Needed to add the bootstrap icon!

    // widget code contained in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js file
    // use the zebra stripe widget if you plan on hiding any rows (filter widget)
    widgets : [ "uitheme", "filter", "zebra" ],

     widgetOptions : {
      // using the default zebra striping class name, so it actually isn't included in the theme variable above
      // this is ONLY needed for bootstrap theming if you are using the filter widget, because rows are hidden
      zebra : ["even", "odd"],

      // reset filters button
      filter_reset : ".reset",

      // extra css class name (string or array) added to the filter element (input or select)
      filter_cssFilter: "form-control",

      // set the uitheme widget to use the bootstrap theme class names
      // this is no longer required, if theme is set
      // ,uitheme : "bootstrap"

      }
    })
     .tablesorterPager({

    // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
    container: $(".ts-pager"),

    // target the pager page select dropdown - choose a page
    cssGoto  : ".pagenum",

    // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
    // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
    removeRows: false,

    // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}';
    // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
    output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})'

    });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ive just determined that it works with the blue theme as opposed to the bootstrap theme which is good enough for me

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why the unsorted Bootstrap icon was not showing up is because the `theme.bootstrap.css` file was not loaded.

If you [look at that file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/css/theme.bootstrap.css#L53), you will see that there is a `.bootstrap-icon-unsorted` definition that adds the unsorted arrow as a background png.